# Windows Forms Example with EmguCV - Could not load file or assembly 'Emgu.CV.World' (Code 0x80131040)

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2017, .net-assembly, emgucv

What I'm trying to do is use an instance of EmguCV's own ImageViewer class from the Emgu.CV.UI namespace in the default template Visual Studio 2017 loads when a Windows Forms application project is created.

For some reason, on the following line

```
Application.Run(new ImageViewer());
```

I am getting the following runtime error from running the program, outputted in Debug Mode as:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileLoadException' in Emgu.CV.UI.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in Emgu.CV.UI.dll
Could not load file or assembly 'Emgu.CV.World, Version=3.3.0.2824, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
   at Emgu.CV.UI.ImageBox..ctor()
   at Emgu.CV.UI.ImageViewer.InitializeComponent()
   at Emgu.CV.UI.ImageViewer..ctor()
   at EmguCVUITest2.Program.Main() in C:\Users\<USER_NAME>\Documents\Visual Studio Projects\EmguCVUITest2\EmguCVUITest2\Program.cs:line 21
```

This is the code I'm running:

Program.cs (almost default code except for line 21)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using Emgu.CV.UI;

namespace EmguCVUITest2
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new ImageViewer());
        }
    }
}
```

Form1.cs (Default Code)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace EmguCVUITest2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Form1.Designer.cs (Default Code)

```
namespace EmguCVUITest2
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.Text = "Form1";
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

I added references in the project to Emgu.CV.DebuggerVisualizers.VS2017, Emgu.CV.UI, Emgu.CV.UI.GL, and Emgu.CV.World. I also configured the project to be built for x86 with Platform Target set to x86. And in the folder where the solution was built, I added cvextern.dll from \bin\x86 of the EmguCV directory, as well as the other library files from there.

Did I miss something?